# Align value to the centre of CircularProgressIndicator flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a `CircularProgressIndicator` which shows how many questions are done. I placed it inside a stack, along with the text that displays that. I would also like to display some text above these which says what they are, 'Questions attempted' but as soon as I place the stack and the text widget in a column, the number of questions done isn't aligned in the centre of the progress indicator. Can anyone please tell me why that happens?

A simplified version of the code displaying the progress indicator:

```
class _ProgressIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Center(
            child: Text(
          '$attemptedQuestions/ $totalQuestions',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        )),
        Center(
            child: SizedBox(
          height: progressBarSize,
          width: progressBarSize,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: attemptedQuestions / totalQuestions,
            ....
```

and the code that displays both the text and the progress indicator:

```
class _AttemptedQuestions extends StatelessWidget {
  ....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
    return Container(
      height: topViewHeight,
      width: topViewWidth,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text('Attempted Questions:', style: textStyle)),
            _ProgressIndicator(...),
          ]),
          ....
```

The result is:

[image]

What I want is to have the number at the centre like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy, paste and run the full code below to see desired output:-

You can try like this.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Attempted Questions:",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 207,
                      height: 207,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "3/3",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had just come back to answer the question. The problem was indeed alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center in the Stack.

Comment: Yes, actually it was that simple just a Stack - Alignment.center.